# Cannot import database postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm just starting with postgresql and I'm trying to import a database using Postbird but I get that error:
[image: Postbird error on import database]

I've installed postgresql-client as suggested but still getting the error.
So I tried using the CLI instead.
I successfully created my database baseball:
`postgres=# CREATE DATABASE baseball;`

and I granted all privileges to my user:
`postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE baseball TO postgres;`

But then when I run `postgres@dev-L140PU:~$ psql -U postgres -d baseball < /home/dev/Document/codecademy/TheBestOfBaseballAwards/baseball_database.sql`, I get this error:
`-bash: /home/dev/Document/codecademy/TheBestOfBaseballAwards/baseball_database.sql: Permission denied`.

How can I solve this please?

Comment: Change the permissions, that error is pretty clear.

Comment: I don't understand, what permissions need to be changed? How can I do that?

Comment: You are running as `postgres@dev-L140PU` which to me means as user `postgres` on machine `dev-L140PU`. The file is under `/home/dev/...`  which would be user `dev` on `dev-L140PU`. The permission error is because user `postgres` does not have permissions on the files under `/home/dev`. Easiest way to do this is to log in as `dev@dev-L140PU` and then run the `psql` command. It may mean adjusting lines in `pg_hba.conf`, but tried it first before we go down that path.

Comment: Thanks both, I moved my database to `/usr/lib/postgresql/` where the user postgres has access to and it worked. I'm still interested in your option of login as dev but I'm not sure I understand. I never created the role dev, dev is just the default user on my machine, if I run `psql` as dev, I get that error `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "dev" does not exist
`. I would also be interested in giving my postgres user access to my `/home` directory if there is a way to do that.

Comment: `psql` is a client program it can run anywhere. The  database user you connect as is determined by  `-U`, so logged in at command line as OS user `dev` run `psql -U postgres -d baseball`. Then you will be connecting as Postgres user `postgres` while being able to access the files in `/home/dev`. No need to give permissions to `postgres` user to the files.  For more info see [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) *Connecting to a Database* and [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) *34.1.2. Parameter Key Words*